# Using TensorFlow libraries on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

For feature extraction of my Keras trained model, I was looking for a signal processing library to compute log mel spectograms on IOS, using Swift. During development I used scikit.signal library in Python for feature extraction.

Then I noticed Tensorflow has support for signal processing:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.signal

I also know that we can import our tf models to be used by core ml during IOS development. I wonder but couldn't find evidence that if I can also take adventage of these **tf signal processing libraries on IOS**. Maybe by making them a part of my model, use them instead of scikit.signal library on desktop. Then when I import it, it is part of my model, or something like that? I also see something called tf-lite, but dont know if it includes these libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding TensorFlow Lite, there are a few things you can look into:

- TensorFlow Lite now implements `Mfcc` and `AudioSpectrogram` as [custom ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/558974db23ee0ea8845ba4b0b7fa94f70408ac1b/tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.cc#L292). You can try to follow the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/devguide#2_convert_the_model_format) to convert a TensorFlow model to TensorFlow Lite model, and add `--allow_custom_ops` argument when running `tflite_convert` tool. See if it works.
- If the previous approach doesn't work, TensorFlow Lite has an experimental feature [Using TensorFlow Lite with select TensorFlow ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/using_select_tf_ops). It supports `Mfcc` and `AudioSpectrogram` operations.

Comment: Could you check this ? tnx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658336/keras-how-to-preprocess-input-signal