# Keras how to preprocess input signal

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, coremltools

I want to preprocess the input of my Keras model with certain signal processing functions as below. I want these to be part of my model because I will (hopefully) convert these to tf-lite or coreml. So I dont have to re-write these functionality on mobile app again. Although I couldn't figure out how and where I should add these to my model so inputs are preprocessed?

```
#method to preprocess the model input, when called
def getMfcss();
 stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(signals, frame_length=frame_length, frame_step=frame_step, fft_length=fft_length)
 ....
 mfccs = tf.contrib.signal.mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms(log_mel_spectrograms)[..., :num_mfccs]
```

And Model goes something like :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=16000, activation='relu'))
```

Comment: Can you add an image of your computation graph? Can you show us some sample code? That'll make it easier to determine for your case where is best

Comment: Is your code exactly like that? An MCVE would really help out here especially since this is bordering a design question (and not a programming question)

Comment: @Ian Quah Tnx But regardles of my code or how my my model looks like it should be possible or not possible to preprocess my input with the given tf functions above. That IS my question. I can have a 1 layer dense function like above, answer should stay same, its about input processing. I am not sure you understand the question well

Comment: Yeah but you can't load numpy tensors on your mobile app, or at least you shouldn't when using TF. THAT's what I'm asking. I don't care about your model - that part is irrelevant. I'm basically asking if you're using `tf.data.Datasets` or `tf.data.QueueRunners`. In production and deployed tensorflow, if you want to add pre-processing to your mobile app to do everything in tensorflow, they become part of your computation graph

Comment: @IanQuah this is exactly how my code looks like. I do not use or know any of the fancy things like you mentioned like tf.data.QueueRunners etc https://github.com/Azure/DataScienceVM/blob/master/Tutorials/DeepLearningForAudio/Deep%20Learning%20for%20Audio%20Part%202b%20-%20Train%20and%20Predict%20on%20UrbanSound%20dataset.ipynb